# Jawbone / fitbit wearables protocol

Tags: fitbit, jawbone

I'm experiencing issues in finding protocol specification on how to interact with fitbit/jawbone bracelets.
Actually the main thing I need, is to detect if a user has pressed the button on it and react somehow on either android device or ios device.

Answer (score 1):

Currently both the bands (Fitbit,Jawbone) are not allowing 3rd parties to directly connect to their band. 3rd parties can connect to their cloud server and access their APIs to get user info using Oauth Authentication.